# What is the difference between relationship, edge and link?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

When I was reading about the theory of graph databases I found the different terms that denote connections between nodes. What is the difference between relationships, edges and links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the terms relationship, edge and link. It is just a matter of the term that the author has decided to use.